# Digital signature using canvas element doesn't work on Android

Tags: javascript, html

I created this site where you can sign digitally on a canvas.
I tried this site on an iPhone device and it works correctly but when I try to switch to Android it starts having problems.

here is the javascript:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="it">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Singature Pad</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='app.css') }}">
</head>
<body>
  <form class="signature-pad-form" method="POST">
    <canvas height="250" width="500" class="signature-pad"></canvas>
    <button class="clear-button">Cancella</button>
    <button class="submit-button" type="submit">Salva</button>
  </form>
  <script>
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const form = document.querySelector('.signature-pad-form');
const clearButton = document.querySelector('.clear-button');


const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.fillStyle = 'white'; // Imposta il colore di riempimento dello sfondo
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); // Riempie il canvas con lo sfondo bianco
ctx.strokeStyle = 'black'; // Imposta il colore delle linee della firma


let writingMode = false;

const handlePointerDown = (event) => {
  writingMode = true;
  ctx.beginPath();
  const [positionX, positionY] = getCursorPosition(event);
  ctx.moveTo(positionX, positionY);
}

const handlePointerUp = () => {
  writingMode = false;
}

const handlePointerMove = (event) => {
  if (!writingMode) return;
  const [positionX, positionY] = getCursorPosition(event);
  ctx.lineTo(positionX, positionY);
  ctx.stroke();
}

const getCursorPosition = (event) => {
  const positionX = event.clientX - event.target.getBoundingClientRect().x;
  const positionY = event.clientY - event.target.getBoundingClientRect().y;
  return [positionX, positionY];
}

ctx.lineWidth = 3;
ctx.lineJoin = ctx.lineCap = 'round';

form.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const imageURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
  const imageBlob = dataURItoBlob(imageURL);

  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('firma', imageBlob);

  fetch('/firma', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData
  })
  .then(response => {
    if (response.ok) {
      // Firma salvata con successo
      clearPad();
      form.reset();
      window.location.href = "{{ url_for('succ') }}"
    } else {
      // Errore durante il salvataggio della firma
      console.error('Errore durante il salvataggio della firma.');
    }
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error('Si è verificato un errore:', error);
  });
});

const clearPad = () => {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
}


clearButton.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  clearPad();
});

canvas.addEventListener('pointerdown', handlePointerDown, { passive: true });
canvas.addEventListener('pointerup', handlePointerUp, { passive: true });
canvas.addEventListener('pointermove', handlePointerMove, { passive: true });

function dataURItoBlob(dataURI) {
  const byteString = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
  const mimeString = dataURI.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0];
  const ab = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
  const ia = new Uint8Array(ab);

  for (let i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
    ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
  }

  return new Blob([ab], { type: mimeString });
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I think the problem may be in the javascript but honestly I can't figure out how to do it.
I tried using an Android tablet and it doesn't work, I tried again on an Android phone and it draws but not well. it seems that as soon as I press the cursor it goes away when I try to go downwards

Comment: What problems are you talking about? Please be specific. Also can you please turn this into a runnable snippet here in SO?

Comment: please also post the HTML structure.